# UPSERT function for elastica?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastica

I would like to do batch updates in elastic search using elastica. The data comes from a postgresql db and the es id's are the same as psql id's. After an operation in the sql db id`s and it's data can be changed, deleted or inserted.

When doing batch updates on id`s in es which don't exist, an exeption is thrown - that is bad.
When trying to delete an id which doesn't exist, also an exeption follows - also bad.

Is there an elegant and efficient solution to do batch updates avoiding exeptions?

Answer (score 1):

Can't say about elastica, but you can use elasticsearch [bulk API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html#bulk-update) + [upsert](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#upserts) over curl. It feels quite nasty but should work.